# Clarification of Krull-Schmidt categories

Tags: category-theory

A Krull-Schmidt category is a category $C$ where every object decomposes into a direct sum of objects with local endomorphism rings.

Now, the notion of a direct-sum is not valid in a general categorical to my knowledge so my guess is that they mean biproduct (at least in the additive categories I'm working in). Is this correct and just an abuse of notation is happening or...?

Comment: What is your categorical definition of a direct sum? Feel free to restrict to whatever class of categories you need for it to make sense.

Comment: In order to even say “endomorphism ring” the category already needs to be at least preadditive. The Wikipedia definition requires additivity, and then it’s clear that we’re talking about biproducts.